# Make an already existing instance available to my jersey resources?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have a jersey resource which needs a specific instance of a class to function. I'm having trouble finding out how to supply this instance to my resource.

When i need to inject a singleton in my resource i use SingletonTypeInjectableProvider, but i can't use that for an already existing object instance which i want to inject.

I currently create my jersey server like:

```
ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.resources");
HttpServer httpServer = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer("http://localhost:9998/", rc);
```

Is there a way to add a resource manually to jersey server, for example:

```
Resource res=new Resource(myinstance);
jersey.addResource(res)
```

Or is there maybe a way to supply an instance to a InjectableProvider and than manually add this injectable provider to jersey, for example:

```
InjectableProvider ip=new InjectableProvider(myinstance)
jersey.addInjectableProvider(ip)
```

Or is there maybe another way to make an already existing instance available to my jersey resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can add an attribute to the `ServletContext` before run the server.
Something like

```
ServletContainer s = new ServletContainer();
// Add the Servlet to the context ...
// Deploy context to the server ...
s.getServletContext().setAttribute("myRc", new MyRc());
httpServer.start();
```

And then in Provider

```
@Provider
public class MyRcProvider implements ContextResolver<MyRc>{
    @Context ServletContext sc; 
    @Override
    public MyRc getContext(Class<?> arg0) {

        return (MyRc)sc.getAttribute("myRc");
    }

}
```

To do this way I think it will be easier to create HttpServer by your own rather than use `GrizzlyServerFactory`. Read the source code of `GrizzlyServerFactory` will be very helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Thumbs up! I took me almost an entire afternoon, but it should now be working, can't test it yet, but it looks good. I had major problems with grizzle which seem to have renamed most of the classes most online example use. Thumbs up!